# Merge columns and drop extra rows

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, rows

I'm trying to merge two dataframes by their common column and drop the leftover rows.

My first df looks something like this:

[image: first df]

The second looks like this:

[image: second df]

As they have a different number of rows, I'd like the final table to have the same amount of rows as the first df, and to drop any duplicate or leftover rows from the second df. The end result should look like this:

[image: third df]

Thank you in advance for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Join and then use unique to remove repeating rows. I use the wonderful package `tidyverse`.

```
> library(tidyverse)
> 
> dat_1 <- data.frame('state' = c('California', 'New York'))
> dat_2 <- data.frame('state' = c('New York', 'New York', 'California'),
+                     'abb'   = c('NY', 'NY', 'CA'))
> 
> dat_1
       state
1 California
2   New York
> dat_2
       state abb
1   New York  NY
2   New York  NY
3 California  CA
> 
> left_join(dat_1, dat_2, by = 'state') %>% unique()
       state abb
1 California  CA
2   New York  NY
```

Comment: Icymi: The `dplyr`-function for `unique` is called `distinct`.

Answer (score 2):

You can try `merge` from base R like below

```
merge(df1,unique(df2))
```